# Installing QuantLib

Tags: anaconda, quantlib

I am installing QuantLib on my computer and I am following the instructions on this link; http://www.cs.utah.edu/~cxiong/Files/Misc/QuantLib_Python.html

I am now on step 7 and on trying to run the command in the Anaconda Prompt I am getting the error below;

```
    (C:\Users\me\Anaconda3) C:\Users\me> cd C:\local\QuantLib-SWIG-master\Python

(C:\Users\me\Anaconda3) C:\local\QuantLib-SWIG-master\Python> set INCLUDE=C:\local\boost_1_66_0

(C:\Users\me\Anaconda3) C:\local\QuantLib-SWIG-master\Python> set LIB=C:\local\boost_1_66_0\lib64-msvc-14.0

(C:\Users\me\Anaconda3) C:\local\QuantLib-SWIG-master\Python> set QL_DIR=C:\local\QuantLib-1.11

(C:\Users\me\Anaconda3) C:\local\QuantLib-SWIG-master\Python> python setup.py build
  File "setup.py", line 2
    Copyright (C) 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003 RiskMap srl
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

What could I have done wrong?

Comment: Did you change `setup.py`?  In the release, the line with the copyrights is line 3, not 2.

Comment: No, I didn't change anything in file setup.py. I didn't even try to open that file. What should I do now?

Comment: What are the first three or four lines of the file?

Comment: @LuigiBallabio The first 4 lines of the file are `1. # -*- coding: iso-8859-1 -*-
2. """
 3. Copyright (C) 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003 RiskMap srl
 4. Copyright (C) 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008 StatPro Italia srl`

Comment: They look as expected.  Please write to the QuantLib mailing list, this is not the place for going back and forth and diagnosing problems.